# C# - Sharing information between instances

Tags: c#, instances

My code is quite simple. When I click a button in the first class it creates two instances of Master and one instance of Arena. Arena needs to receive information from both Master instances and Arena needs to send information to each Master instances, but the information is not the same for both Master instances.

```
//When I press a button...
master = new Master(ip1.Text);
master.Show();

slave = new Master(ip2.Text);
slave.Show();

arena = new Arena(master,slave);
arena.Show();
```

ARENA CLASS:

```
private Master master;
private Master slave;

public Arena(Master master,Master slave)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.master = master;
    this.slave = slave;

}
```

My question is:

I can create new Arena(master,slave) because the instances master and slave are created before. But I need to use something like:

```
master = new Master(ip1.Text,arena);
master.Show();

slave = new Master(ip2.Text,arena);
slave.Show();

arena = new Arena(master,slave);
arena.Show();
```

But I cant do this because when master and slave instances are created, arena = null.
**FIXED!!**

**EDIT:**

I have a instance called Arena that receives the instances Master and Slave as an argument.

```
    private Master master;
    private Master slave;

    public Arena(Master master,Master slave)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.master = master;
        this.slave = slave;

    }
```

My question is how can I return different values for master and slave.
For example:

```
public int missao_enviada;


 private void btn_enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
missao_enviada = 1;
 }

   public int enviou_missao()
    {
        return missao_enviada;
    }
```

But I only want to return missao_enviada to Master master instance and not Master slave instance.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Simple fact is, you can't call both constructors and have all dependencies satisfied in this way. You will have to add methods to set values (or just set the properties directly) onto one of the two class definitions

Comment: Yes. It was an example. I want to include  the instance arena in master and slave, so I can use the functions.

Comment: So your solution is to add getter/setters for these properties on `Arena` (or methods to set them)

Comment: Even with get,set I still need to create the instance Arena = new Arena(master,slave) in master and slave right? I cant create another instance of arena

Comment: Yes, but you can't pass master/slave in the constructor - you need to remove master/slave from the constructor.

Comment: If I remove it , it says not enough field arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign Arena to Master And Slave in Arena's constructor method

```
private Master master;
private Master slave;

public Arena(Master master,Master slave)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.master = master;
    this.slave = slave;

    master.Arena = this;
    slave.Arena = this;
}
```

You should modify your Master class and add Arena property to it

```
public class Master
{
    public Arena Arena { set; get;}
}
```

Comment: there is no master.Arena method

Comment: @TiagoSilva you should add Arena property to Master class

Comment: Thank you. This seem to be the solution.

Comment: I only have one last question. Can you help me. Thanks I will edit my post

Comment: @TiagoSilva Sure, but if it's a different question, I suggest posting another question

Comment: I cant post a new question. I'm a new member.

Answer (score 3):

Is this something you want?

```
    arena = new Arena();
    master = new Master(ip1.Text,arena);
    master.Show();

    slave = new Master(ip2.Text,arena);
    slave.Show();

    arena.SetMaster(master);
    arena.SetSlave(slave);

    arena.Show();
```

---

As per comment (inside `Arena` class):

```
// Empty constructor
public Arena()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Do your stuff...
}

public void SetMaster(Master m) // Or use property; create similar for SetSlave
{
  master = m;
}
```

Comment: I will try. I reply soon. Thanks.

Comment: There isnt anything called SetMaster or SetSlave. And when I create arena = new Arena(); throws an error saying there is not enough arguments.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Well then you can create an empty constructor too. And setter methods you need to add too.

Comment: @TiagoSilva see answer. But these are really basic things, if you couldn't do that what I wrote in last comment, I wonder how you will do rest of the tast

Comment: Thanks. This is also a solution. Can you check me edit please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution will be to create a static class with static variables which will be used across all master and slaves. Another solution could be to create SQL light database.

Comment: I cant create static fields because the information of master and slave are different.